# Replace all instances of one value with NAs in a numeric vector

Tags: r, vector, numeric

I have a numeric vector of values between 1 and 7 (called in the hypothetical example below "Numeric").

How would I create a new variable ("Numericnomid" which contains the same numeric information but where all values of 4 in "Numeric" are now valued as NA? I know this might seem like silly code (I'm learning!) But I tried:

```
Numericnommid<-[Numeric==4] <- NA
```

But this just makes my new vector one with just one value - NA!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```r
Numericnomid <- Numeric
Numericnomid[Numericnomid==4] <- NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one liner

```r
Numericnomid <- ifelse(Numeric==4, NA, Numeric)
```